# iOS audio file not playing in a desktop web browser

Tags: ios, html, avaudiorecorder

Why Safari/Chrome can not play the file created using AVAudioRecorder ?

Here's my recorder settings :

```
private static let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey: 128000,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: NSNumber(long: AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue)
    ]
```

And the reader :

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="MD_31E5106A-2901-49ED-8492-D29A654B826D" type="audio/mp4">
</audio>
```

I tried several settings, no success. All files are playable with VLC.

Here is a sample file: http://cl.ly/1l0z231x322l

*Edit: reader code*

Comment: have you checked the codec of the video?? Mention the codec of your video

Comment: The value of `AVNumberOfChannelsKey` key should be 1 instead of 2 as you're recording only single channel audio file. Also please save the file with `.aac` extension.

Comment: I tried with 1 channel too.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Your file is a [CAF/Core Audio Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio_Format), and AAC/caf is even less widely supported than AAC/m4a (not even iTunes plays caf files).

You could try converting it to .m4a and using the content-type `audio/mp4` or converting it .aac and using `audio/aac`.

Or .mp3 `audio/mpeg`.

**PREVIOUSLY**

AAC/m4a is not a very widely supported format. You're better off using MP3.

Comment: I got some music in AAC. All work on Chrome and Safari. I encounter the same issue with mp3

Comment: What content type did you use for MP3? How about content type audio/m4a? Or using raw AAC and audio/aac?

Comment: I use kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3 and audio/mp3. I think we found the solution

Comment: I don't think that's the right content type - I think it should be audio/mpeg

Answer (score 0):

It works if we had the an extension to the URL

```
recordURL = recordURL.URLByAppendingPathExtension("m4a") 
recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: recordURL, settings: AudioRecorder.settings)
```

Comment: So this was a 404 problem?

Comment: Nope, i don't know why but if we save the record as a file with an extension, the web browser can play it. Even if you remove the extension after saving the record.

Comment: So the lesson is: do not save a record without its file extension

Comment: Weird - but how did `src="test.m4a"` work not 404 if the file had no extension?

Comment: In fact i though if i had an extension it will play but no. I will edit the question.

Comment: Yes its kind of weird